# Using Two IDEs ( xCode and VS 2015) for one project

Tags: xcode, git, visual-studio

I am struggling to get this right..

I do alot of work on my laptop using xCode.
My desktop is a win10 machine using VS.

I am  using git on my mac but only using it on one machine.

I would like to use both machines to edit and commit to my assignments, etc.

My question is how may I accomplish this...I have exhausted google searches and 
get more confused than anything, and I am sure this is simple.

When I create an xCode project, I will create multiple targets
as there might be 2 or 3 problems per assignment.
Xcode then creates a project file, etc.

When I go to my windows PC, if I go into VS and clone the repo,
there is not a compatible project file ( obviously, as its not xCode).

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?  Keep in 
mind I am a beginner with git.

Also, if I use a gitignore file and put it in the repo after the 
repo has already had commits, will it drop and delete the 
now ignored files moving forward?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no simple conversion, especially if you go back and forth frequently. You need to use something like CMake to generate both projects from a common set of scripts. It's not simple, but it's worth learning.

Comment: Or, you can use a single IDE that works on both mac and windows. QtCreator and Visual Studio Code are two examples.